# Company CAs, what are the privacy risks for the employees?

Tags: privacy, certificate-authority

The company I work in as an intern is using CA spoofing.

When I check the certificate I have :

- Issued to : security.stackexchange.com
- Issued by : *name of my company* CA

So here I'm sure that this is CA spoofing. 
It is the same on other websites as github, tensorflow ...

My questions are :

1. Is CA spoofing a common thing for companies ?
2. What are the pros and cons of CA spoofing (for the company) ?
3. Do employees have to fear something about their privacy ?

Comment: They want to monitor what you do on their network.

Comment: It is not "spoofing" anything. They are the issuer of trusted certs in that environment.

Comment: @schroeder so it is just the company issuing their own certs, without any idea of getting a hand on the information the employees share on different websites ?

Comment: 1) yes it is very common, 2) they get to inspect to see if unauthorised data is leaving, 3) there is no employee privacy in this situation

Comment: The duplicate explains: the purpose is to be *able* to read all traffic. Whether they do, or not, is up to several factors.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't see it that way